# Find necessary and sufficient conditions on a subset $S$ of a group $G$ for $S=\langle S\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Find necessary and sufficient conditions on a subset $S$ of a group $G$ for $S=\langle S\rangle.$

Ok, so the order of the subgroup generated by the set needs to equal the set. This would work for the identity wouldn't it?

Comment: Use `$\langle S\rangle$` for $\langle S\rangle$.

Comment: *NB:* $$G\cong \langle G\rangle.$$

Comment: You realize, of course, that this condition holds exactly when $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: "The order of the subgruop generated by the set needs to equal the set"... true, but not sufficient. The set of primes generates the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$, and has the same cardinality as the group it generates. What you are *really* being asked is something you can check in $S$. You know, like things you check in a subset to verify it is in fact a subgroup...